# SOAP call with duplicate keys using PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to do a SOAP call in PHP 5 with repeating objects like so:

```
<sources>
  <source>
    <name>somename</name>
    <id>someid</id>
  </source>
 <source>
    <name>somename</name>
    <id>someid</id>
  </source>
</sources>
```

The following code works fine for 1 source:

```
$data = [
  'sources' => [
    'source' => [
      'name' => 'somename',
      'id' => 'someid'
    ]
  ]
]
```

How can I do a SOAP call with this data using the __soapCall function, since it expects an array, and arrays can not have duplicate keys in PHP.

What I've tried so far:

```
$data = [
  'sources' => [
    'source' => [
      [
        'name' => 'somename',
        'id' => 'someid'
      ],
      [
        'name' => 'somename',
        'id' => 'someid'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

This results in a "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'name' property".

```
$data = [
  'sources' => [
    'source' => [
      (object) [
        'name' => 'somename',
        'id' => 'someid'
      ],
      (object) [
        'name' => 'somename',
        'id' => 'someid'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

This results also in a "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'name' property".

```
$data = [
  'sources' => [
    [
      'name' => 'somename',
      'id' => 'someid'
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'somename',
      'id' => 'someid'
    ]
  ]
]
```

This results also in a "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'source' property". I tried this because I've found it as an answer to a simular question: [Multiple elements of same name in PHP SOAP Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546087/multiple-elements-of-same-name-in-php-soap-call).

Comment: I think the PHP SoapClient requires a object instead of an array. Try to convert `$data` to an object. `$data = (object)$data;`

Comment: I dont think this is the solution, since this format works fine when I'm only posting 1 source (see first example, just added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [found the solution myself](https://www.phpflow.com/php/how-to-convert-xml-to-associative-array/). I have written the XML message as xml-string which I now programmatically convert to an array:

```
$sourcesAsXml = "<root><source><name>a</name></source><source><name>b</name></source></root>"
$dataArray = ['sources' => json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($sourcesAsXml)))]
```

This outputs the following:

```
array ('sources' =>
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'source' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'name' => 'a',
    )),
    1 =>
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'name' => 'b',
    )),
  ),
))
)
```